# Optimize read-only Mysql slave

Tags: mysql, postgresql, optimization, database-replication, master-slave

I'm having trouble for a delta loading project of mine :)

**Context:** my Postgres-based data warehouse is pulling data from my Mysql-based webshop everyday. We set up a read-only slave for this, and i think it's the maximum the IT will give me as support, ie nothing will be done to the master to help me.

**Situation:** I wan to pull the most recently created or updated rows from MySQL to Postgres. Something like every 15-30min. So the lag in my data warehouse is something like 30min max in the end of the process.
Tehrefore a quick loop on every table needed with a simple condition on dates should be sufficient.

**Problem:** the webshop DBs are quite big and it takes a while to process each table (up to 1min per table, dates are not indexed and there is no partitioning), which compromises the whole project...

**Question:** Can I optimize that read-only mysql slave (with no operation on the master)?

Thanks a lot!
V.

Cheers,
Vincent

Comment: Do your tables have a auto increment primary key? You could use that. Failing that you could convert the bin log itself to SQL and replay it on postgres? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog-row-events.html

Comment: So *why* are there no indexes on the dates, and why have you ruled that out as an option?

Comment: You have a perfectly good MySQL Slave?  And you can process the stuff there?  Why add 30min to the delay by copying data to yet another machine?

Comment: The usual solution to DW "reporting" is to build and maintain "Summary Tables".   If you would like to discuss this, pleas provide more details about the schema and the reports.

Comment: @JoeDoherty they sometimes do, and I didn't think of using them. I'll make some test with this and get back to you with the results. Yet, rows are updated from time to time up to a year back... because of some of particular business process we have :)

Comment: @RichardHuxton We are a startup and our 10+ magento webshops have suffered weird implementation and maintenance; at the moment, our IT team refuses to increase its weight... I know :)

Comment: @RickJames the slave is perfectly good yes, but it's mysql. Although it would be heaven to keep the same environment, I have a strong preference for postgres when it comes to DWH.. Did I answer the question?

Comment: @RickJames well, I'm  already using summary tables. Yet, another constraint of mine is that I have to get that raw data from our OLTP DBs because I'm using it for operational processes that require the lowest granularity. Eventually, I really think it all about optimizing my queries in the mysql slave...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the people interested, here is the solution i came up with:

I basically added indexes on the slave (not on the master). Problem solved.
Interestingly, this is possible with Mysql DBs because the replication process is using logs, etc.

Cheers,
V.